# Serialization Benchmark

Tags: serialization, benchmarking, deserialization

I'm writing a benchmark  for computing the time taken  for serialization/de-serialization for [OpenFast](http://www.openfast.org/)

The question is when I'm computing the time taken, should I also take into account the time taken for parsing and setting the values for fields and also the same while de-serialization.

I'm writing it in java so what accuray is good Nano or Milli?  Are there any issues in nano second computation that I should be worried about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *Effective Java*, Edition 2, Item 69:

> For interval
>   timing, always use System.nanoTime in preference to System.currentTime-
>   Millis. System.nanoTime is both more accurate and more precise, and it is not
>   affected by adjustments to the system’s real-time clock.